# Changing positions of SplitApp Master/Details Pages

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Does anyone know how to change the location/position of the `Master Page` of a `SplitApp`?  By default it is always on the left hand side.  I want to be able to put one on the right hand side (or even have the master page on the top, as a header).

Are there any other objects I can use instead to achieve this?  `SplitApp` is required as we want to navigate the details pages without changing the master page.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [`sap.ui.unified.sample.SplitContainer`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.SplitContainer/preview) with `orientation: Horizontal`

But yes, this [control](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.SplitContainer.html) doesn't have something like master and detail pages unlike SplitApp. But you have to find workaround on click events and by changing the `secondaryContent` and `content` accordingly.

> Note that this control is still in experimental mode